# How do I add Student objects to an array through the use of a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have tried to add students to the array through the use of a for loop that checks the current array to make sure that there isn't a student within the array that already has the student's name that is being input.

```
bool found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    resultMessage.Text = "Hello";
    if (newStudent[i] != null)
    {
        string fullName = newStudent[counter].Name();
        if (fullName.ToUpper() == newStudent[i].Name().ToUpper())
        {
            resultMessage.Text = "Name is already in the system.";
            found = true;
        }
    }            
}
if (found == false)
{
    if (counter > 2)
    {
        resultMessage.Text = "Array is full.";
    }
    else
    {
        newStudent[counter] = new Student(StudentID.Text, FirstName.Text, MiddleInitial.Text, LastName.Text, HouseNumber.Text, Street.Text, CityCounty.Text, Country.Text,
        State.Text, ZipCode.Text, DOB.Text);
        resultMessage.Text = "Age: " + newStudent[counter].Age;
    }
}

counter++;
```

The `counter` is static and is incremented at the end of the button's code. It currently will not pass through the `newStudent[i] == null;` statement. It goes to it, thinks the array is empty and continues to the next portion of the code. I am not using much of the HTML code, I am doing all of the functionality through the previous code.

Comment: You seem to be mixing `[i]` and `[counter]` which won't be helping. Also can you post a bit more about `newStudent` and how you create it? This doesn't appear to be the full code.

Comment: Student[] newStudent = new Student[3];

    Student newStudentA;

    static int counter = 0;

This is outside of the buttons within the code file. I have a Student class file created with several constructors, one of them being Name where it pulls the first and last name from the text boxes.

Comment: Correct this part "through the `newStudent[i] != null;` statement." in your question.

Comment: @bishopob In the code of the button, are you able to comment it out and hard code a student object into the array. Then on subsequent clicks, confirm that the student exists? If it doesn't then it might be that the web framework is reconstructing the class on every "click", and will likely need the array to be static.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increase `counter` only while adding a new student, you can do this by returning from the button when a duplicate student is found or maximum counter is reached.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    resultMessage.Text = "Hello";
    if (newStudent[i] != null)
    {
        string fullName = newStudent[counter].Name();
        if (fullName.ToUpper() == newStudent[i].Name().ToUpper())
        {
            resultMessage.Text = "Name is already in the system.";
            return;
        }
    }            
}
if (counter > 2)
{
    resultMessage.Text = "Array is full.";
    return;
}
else
{
    newStudent[counter] = new Student(StudentID.Text, FirstName.Text, MiddleInitial.Text, LastName.Text, HouseNumber.Text, Street.Text, CityCounty.Text, Country.Text,
    State.Text, ZipCode.Text, DOB.Text);
    resultMessage.Text = "Age: " + newStudent[counter].Age;
}
counter++;
```

Comment: That's something I have thought about doing, but the problem really lies in the fact that when I run the code, it won't go through the if (newStudent[i] != null) portion of the code to get to where the name check is.

Comment: Why? This is the first part in the button method. It must reach it.

Comment: I know eventually it must reach that point, but right now the problem is that when I run it, the computer thinks there is no value within the array and skips over that if statement.

Comment: Make sure it enters the loop, and display the contents of the `newStudent` array. You may find where the problem is.

Comment: You may send me the file if possible.

Comment: It’s using visual studio, do you have it? I can send you what I have.

Comment: Yes. I will wait for your file.